# CFDocument isn't showing styles and images. Is HTTPS the problem?

Tags: https, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, cfdocument

I have been using CFDocument for years with no problems. Suddenly the CFDocument is not showing formatting nor static images.

I have heard of the PDF engine crapping out, but other code is generating the documents just fine. And I have rebooted the software.

Is it possible that the HTTPS vs HTTP is the problem.  As the sites functioning fine are http.  I have just noticed this on the https site.

I'm lost.  If it is an https/http problem, what is fix?

```
 <cfdocument 
    format="pdf" 
    filename = "inspection_pdf\#busid#_#inspid#.pdf"
    overwrite = "yes"
    marginBottom = ".6"
    marginLeft = ".4"
    marginRight = ".4"
    marginTop = ".2">

    <style type="text/css">@import "pdf.css";</style>
```

As related, this code above has been working for years with no issues.

Comment: Do the images (when requested via URL) show up in a browser? Is there any redirect (3xx HTTP status code) involved? What TLS version is used on the image's domain?

Comment: It is an HTTPS Issue - currently having to add : http://#cgi.HTTP_HOST#/ in front of things to get working.  But hoping there is an easier solution as I have lots of PDF's with this issue.

Comment: I wish Adobe had a code tag inside CFDocument - allow non SSL? Or something like that.